# Shannon-Fano Compression: Output File Size Issue with Large Trees, Seeking Guidance on Optimization

Tags: python

Trying for the first time implementing Shannon-Fano to compress files. While file itself compresses just fine, the tree itself is huge so sum end file ends up being several times bigger than the original (when it comes to images or pdfs). I need the tree to be in the output file to later decode it. Not sure what I am missing here and how to not make the output file + tree not be this big. Does anyone know how to fix this or what I am missing?
This is the code:

```
#-----------------------OPEN FILE-----------------------
def read_binary_file_in_letters(file_path, k):
    letters = []

    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            while True:
                letter = file.read(k)
                if not letter:
                    break
                letters.append(letter)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: File '{file_path}' not found.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Unable to read file '{file_path}'. {e}")

    return letters


#print(f"letters: {letters}")

#-------------------PROBABILITY CALCULATION----------------------

def calculate_letter_probability(letters):

    # empty dictionary to store letter occurrences
    letter_occurrence = {}

    # total count of letters in the given array
    total_letters = 0

    # Going through each letter in the array
    for letter in letters:
        # updating the occurrences for each letter in the dictionary
        letter_occurrence[letter] = letter_occurrence.get(letter, 0) + 1
        total_letters += 1

    # calculating the probability for each letter - putting it in a dictionary to store letter => probability
    letter_probability = {}

    for letter, occurrences in letter_occurrence.items():
        probability = occurrences / total_letters
        letter_probability[letter] = probability

    # sorting the list of tuples based on the second element of each tuple (the probability) in descending order
    sorted_letters = sorted(letter_probability.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    return sorted_letters


#print(result)

#-------------------SHANNON FANO ALGORITHM----------------------

def shannon_fano(sorted_letters):

    if len(sorted_letters) == 1:
        # if there is only one symbol, return it as is
        return {sorted_letters[0][0]: ''}

    total_probability = sum(prob for _, prob in sorted_letters)
    cumulative_prob = 0
    split_index = 0

    # finding the split index with cumulative probability closest to half
    for i, (_, prob) in enumerate(sorted_letters):
        cumulative_prob += prob
        if cumulative_prob >= total_probability / 2:
            split_index = i
            break

    # dividing the symbols into two subparts
    subpart1 = sorted_letters[:split_index + 1]
    subpart2 = sorted_letters[split_index + 1:]

    # recursively applying Shannon-Fano to each subpart
    codes = {}

    subpart1_codes = shannon_fano(subpart1)
    subpart2_codes = shannon_fano(subpart2)

    # add '0' as a prefix to the codes for symbols in subpart1
    for symbol, subcode in subpart1_codes.items():
      codes[symbol] = '0' + subcode

    # add '1' as a prefix to the codes for symbols in subpart2
    for symbol, subcode in subpart2_codes.items():
      codes[symbol] = '1' + subcode

    return codes
# -------------------TREE NODE CLASS------------------------------

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

# -------------------BINARY TREE CREATION--------------------------

def create_binary_tree(encoded_chars):
    root = TreeNode(None)
    for char, code in encoded_chars.items():
        current_node = root
        for bit in code:
            if bit == '0':
                if not current_node.left:
                    current_node.left = TreeNode(None)
                current_node = current_node.left
            elif bit == '1':
                if not current_node.right:
                    current_node.right = TreeNode(None)
                current_node = current_node.right
        current_node.value = char
    return root

# -------------------PRINT TREE------------------------------------

def print_tree(node, code="", level=0, prefix="Root: "):
    if node is not None:
        if node.value is not None:
            print(f"{' ' * (level * 4)}{prefix} {node.value}: {code}")
        if node.left is not None:
            print_tree(node.left, code + "0", level + 1, "L--- ")
        if node.right is not None:
            print_tree(node.right, code + "1", level + 1, "R--- ")

# -------------------SERIALIZE TREE------------------------------------

def serialize_tree(node):
    if node is None:
        return 'None'
    left_serialized = serialize_tree(node.left)
    right_serialized = serialize_tree(node.right)
    return f"{node.value}:{left_serialized}:{right_serialized}"

# -------------------DESERIALIZE TREE------------------------------------

def deserialize_tree(serialized_tree):
    def helper(tokens):
        token = tokens.pop(0)
        if token == 'None':
            return None
        node = TreeNode(token)
        node.left = helper(tokens)
        node.right = helper(tokens)
        return node

    tokens = serialized_tree.split(':')
    return helper(tokens)

# -----------------------ENCODING TEXT--------------------------
def encode_text(original_text, encoding_dict, k):
    encoded_text = ""
    for char in original_text:
        if char in encoding_dict:
            encoded_text += encoding_dict[char].ljust(k, '0')  # Pad with zeros to make the code length k
        else:
            # If the character is not in the encoding dictionary, keep it unchanged
            encoded_text += char
    return encoded_text


# -----------------------WRITE TO FILES-----------------------
def write_encoded_text_and_tree_to_files(encoded_text, serialized_tree, output_file_path, tree_file_path):
    try:
        # Write encoded text using a bit-wise approach
        with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as file:
            bit_buffer = 0
            bit_count = 0
            for bit in encoded_text:
                bit_buffer = (bit_buffer << 1) | int(bit)
                bit_count += 1
                if bit_count == 8:
                    file.write(bytes([bit_buffer]))
                    bit_buffer = 0
                    bit_count = 0
            # Write any remaining bits
            if bit_count > 0:
                file.write(bytes([bit_buffer << (8 - bit_count)]))
        print(f"Encoded text written to '{output_file_path}'.")

        with open(tree_file_path, 'w') as tree_file:
            tree_file.write(serialized_tree)
        print(f"Serialized tree written to '{tree_file_path}'.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: Unable to write encoded text or serialized tree to files. {e}")


# -----------------------INPUTS---------------------------------
# Example usage:
input_file_path = 'owl.bmp'
output_file_path = 'owl.compressed'
tree_file_path = 'owl_tree.txt'
k = 8

letters = read_binary_file_in_letters(input_file_path, k)

sorted_letters = calculate_letter_probability(letters)

sorted_symbols = sorted(sorted_letters, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

encoded_letters = shannon_fano(sorted_symbols)

# Create and print the binary tree
root_node = create_binary_tree(encoded_letters)
# print_tree(root_node)

# Encode the text using the generated encoding dictionary
encoded_text = encode_text(letters, encoded_letters, k=8)
print("Encoded Text:", encoded_text)

serialized_tree = serialize_tree(root_node)
# print("Serialized Tree:", serialized_tree)

write_encoded_text_and_tree_to_files(encoded_text, serialized_tree, output_file_path, tree_file_path)
```